# How to get QB client version using qbxml?

Tags: api, locale, quickbooks, qbxml

I'm trying to check if the user connecting to my web app is using Quickbooks Canada or US. Is there a way to retrieve the client version or locale of quickbooks using qbxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From QBSDK ProGuide v12 page 212:

The HostQuery request enables your application to obtain from QuickBooks the product 
name and version information. (However, if you are primarily interested in supported 
version information, and you use QBXMLRP2, then using the QBXMLVersionsForSession 
call invoked against the request processor would be a better choice.)

HostQueryRs shows a field called Country.  The OSR defines it this way:

Country
The country name in an address, or, in returned Host information (HostRet or HostInfo), the country for which this edition of QuickBooks was designed. (Possible values are US, CA, UK, and AU.)